# Codeigniter using routes isn't working?

Tags: php

How to use this things, the routes ?

For example, i my page is

- controller/function

and i want the controller part and the function part to become

- name
- $route['controller/function'] =
  "name";

and i tryed like that, but nothing happens, still when trying to go to controller/function it is controller/function not name

Comment: give us an example of the url you wanna achieve and your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do it the other way round.

actually you define a route to a desired controller function:

```
$route['en/name'] = 'en_controller/name_function';
```

also see here: [CI Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should read the manual URI Routing in CI [URI Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html). There are some examples that will help you understand how to make your routing to work.